# Login issues for some users till they clear cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Users see 404 resource not found error while trying to login and my ELMAH captures below error. User can login when I ask them to clear cookies. Any help is appreciated.
FYI: All the errors captured has url like www.mywebsite.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fHome.aspx&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1. Wonder if AspxAutoDetect has anything to do with it.

```
 < Exception Type =" System.IO.PathTooLongException">
 < Message > The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters. </ Message > 

< StackTrace > at System.IO.PathHelper.GetFullPathName() at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths) at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path) at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath) at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath) at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path) at System.Web.InternalSecurityPermissions.PathDiscovery(String path) at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(String virtualPath) at Xpedite.WebAbstraction.WebRequest.MapPath(String path) at Xpedite.Resources.ResourceUrl..ctor(IWebRequest request, Uri resourceUrl) at Xpedite.Resources.ResourceUrl..ctor(IWebRequest request, String resourceUrl) at Xpedite.WebControls.CompositeResource.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetNamedResources>b__0(Resource resource) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() at Xpedite.Verify.NotNullOrEmpty[T](T value, String paramName) at Xpedite.Resources.ResourceContext.CreateResourceDefinition(ResourceType type, String referenceName, IEnumerable`1 resources) at Xpedite.WebControls.CompositeResource.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) </ StackTrace >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to my configuration file solved the issue.

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1000" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```